# WWW-Authenticate Basic Realm login popup not working on Chrome 117.0.5938.63 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, http-headers, realm

We are using a backend Node.js application to open.pug files on the frontend. When opening a file, basic authentication is required, so we used the "WWW-Authenticate Basic realm" header, which opened a popup when the page loaded for the user to enter their credentials. However, for the past few days, this popup has not been opening on chrome but it works on other browser.

we are sending this header from backend.

```
res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate','Basic realm=""');
```

Chrome Version: **Chrome 117.0.5938.63 (Official Build) (64-bit)**
Could someone please help on this?

Thanks

tried to set this

```
res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', `xBasic realm="${realm}"`);
```

but still not working.

Comment: A quick reminder: Some organisational policies are being applied, and machines outside of our organisation are working with the same version of Chrome. Can anyone suggest a browser setting that might stop this authenticate popup from opening?

Comment: Are you using MongoDB Realm for all of your authentication?

Comment: no, basic http authentication supported by browser based on header:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate

Comment: So what is MongoDB Realm being used for, as tagged in the question? e.g. what role does MongoDB Realm, the database, play in the question?